# Widgets not showing in NBViewer

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have an iPython Notebook with an interactive slider widget:

[image]

To share the notebook, I would like to use the link provided by NBViewer. This would allow me to share the notebook with people that don't use Python.  Unfortunately, the widget does not show when viewing the NBViewer link:

[image]

Is there something I need to do to make widgets work with NBViewer?

Comment: I believe widgets won't work on nbviewer full stop. You could try using Project Jupyter's colaboratory (running on your local machine, they can see and run the notebook through Google Drive w/o python installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets are not shown in nbviewer with current ipython 2.x.

IPython 3 is supposed to add persistent widgets that can be shown by nbviewer.

The release of ipython 3 was scheduled for this fall but it is likely to happen early next year.

Comment: Ok, I'll anxiously await the release of iPython 3.

Comment: Widgets won't work [interactively in nbviwer](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2014-January/013099.html), but with newer versions there should be something static. IPython 3 is out since Feb 27th 2015 and [notebooks display something static](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Using%20Interact.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade ipywidget from version 7.0.3 to get nbviewer showing ipywidget.

```
pip install ipywidgets==6.0.0
```

Comment: I am not clear on this yet. When I downgraded to version 6, the widget would show on nbviewer. But it was not active. 

One needs to have an active kernel running. I have since then experimented using mybinder.org.

Try have a look here:
Github: https://github.com/tlinnet/mybinder_relax/blob/master/plot_sin.ipynb nbviewer: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/tlinnet/mybinder_relax/blob/master/plot_sin.ipynb mybinder.org https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/tlinnet/mybinder_relax/master?filepath=plot_sin.ipynb