# Jupyter Notebook; Nbviewer, not displaying widgets

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134727/widgets-not-showing-in-nbviewer) post, I just upgraded to Jupyter/Python 3.4 so widgets would actually appear when using Nbviewer. Alas, it does not seem to work. Actually, *none* of the interactive widgets from the [examples](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/tree/2.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/) will display on nbviewer - [except the beat frequencies one](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Beat%20Frequencies.ipynb).

Any ideas why this might not work?

Any alternative suggestions to how to make it work are very welcome. [Here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/TMorville/LML/blob/master/Simple_Coin_Game.ipynb) is a link to the bit of code I am trying to get to display sliders in nbviewer, and [here](https://github.com/TMorville/LML/blob/master/Simple_Coin_Game.ipynb) is the github link.

Thanks!